# Defensively Handling ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm wondering what a best practice is for defensively handling ActiveRecord throwing a RecordNotFound exception. It seems that the default Rails behavior is to render a 404 error. That works fine when we're dealing with getting content-- it makes intuitive sense. When I'm doing something like creating an associated record and the parent model's record no longer exists, however, throwing a 404 seems more cryptic.

What if I wanted to, instead, return a validation error complaining that the record no longer exists? How might I go about doing this?

Comment: Can you give an example of the ruby code you're calling when the AR::RecordNotFound gets raised?

Answer (score 2):

You should really never have a 404 error on your website: you should try to catch all errors and handle them gracefully.

It depends where you're getting the error. If you're in a controller, say, in the edit action, you can just use a rescue, perhaps in conjunction with `.exists?` so that no error is even actually thrown. Something like this:

```
def edit
    if Model.exists?(params[:id])
        @model = Model.find(params[:id])
    else
        flash[:error] = "Unable to find model with ID #{params[:id]}!"
        redirect_to models_path
    end
end
```

You can add a model level validation for this as well. Let's say you have a User which belongs to a Group (i.e, it has a group_id). This validation will ensure that not only a group_id is set, but that it maps to a real Group record.

```
# User.rb
validates_presence_of: group
```

That way if you're just throwing params in to a `.create!` or `.save!` method, the validation will fail and you'll get a standard Rails error message.

But, your controller should then use the non-exception throwing versions (`.create` and `.save`) and again you can do something like above to see if the object is valid, then set a flash if it's not.

Comment: I am not sure presence validation is good idea, since it relies on blank? on the association which can be present while the parent_id changes to a non-existing id. No?

Comment: If you did `validates_presence_of: group_id`, then it will only make sure that you entered in an ID number, even if it's invalid. i.e, you could make group_id = -1 and that validation will be happy. However, `validates_presence_of: group` will not only make sure you have to have an ID (so it can't be nil), but that the ID matches a real record (so group_id = -1 will fail).

Answer (score 0):

Use validates_existence gem 
https://github.com/perfectline/validates_existence